# Why is there multiple output when I call from an arraylist?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class BryanList{  
    public static void main (String [] args)
   {  
      ArrayList<String> alist=new ArrayList<String>();  
      alist.add("Bryan");
      alist.add("18");
      alist.add("Chicken Rice");    

      for (int i = 0; i <= alist.size(); i++) {     
         System.out.println ("My Name: "+alist.get(i));
         System.out.println ("Age: "+alist.get(i));
         System.out.println ("Favourite food: "+alist.get(i));      
      }
   }  
}
```

How come its not just displaying just one output instead there's 3 of the same output? Does anyone have any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: See you are using list. for each iteration in for loop it will give each index value.So it the out put will be same for all the print statements. Also this condition is error prone. You will get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. So the condition should be i <= alist.size() - 1

Comment: please be also aware, that with `i<= alist.size()` your loop will terminate when `i==list.size()` but any index starts at `0` and ends at `list.size -1`. So you should make it a `for(int i=0; i< alist.size(); i++)` to avoid an Exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one time output then use generics class structure.

Create one class which you want to save records.

```
class Menu {
    public int age;
    public String name;
    public String favFood;
}
```

You can create getter/setter method if you need. Otherwise just declare variables with `public` keyword.
Create one `ArrayList` which will store object of `Menu` class.

```
ArrayList<Menu> alist = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.name = "Bryan";
    menu.age = 18;
    menu.favFood = "Chicken Rice";
    alist.add(menu);
```

> > Print output

```
for (int i = 0; i <= alist.size(); i++) {
    Menu menu = alist.get(i);
    System.out.println("My Name: " + menu.name);
    System.out.println("Age: " + menu.age);
    System.out.println("Favourite food: " + menu.favFood);
}
```

I updated your class with your requirement, please check.

```
class BryanList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Menu> alist = new ArrayList<Menu>();
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.name = "Bryan";
        menu.age = 18;
        menu.favFood = "Chicken Rice";
        alist.add(menu);

        for (int i = 0; i <= alist.size(); i++) {
            Menu menu = alist.get(i);
            System.out.println("My Name: " + menu.name);
            System.out.println("Age: " + menu.age);
            System.out.println("Favourite food: " + menu.favFood);
        }
    }
}

class Menu {
    public int age;
    public String name;
    public String favFood;
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop check is happening on `alist.size()` which is in your case `3`.

Now, in each iteration, it's printing `alist.get(i)` 3 times.

Suggestion:

Use POJO and add it to your list.

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String favFood;

    public getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public getFavFood(){
        return favFood;
    }

    public setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public setName(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public setName(String favFood){
        this.favFood = favFood;
    }
}
```

And now, your code will work with simple modification.

```
public static void main (String [] args){  
    ArrayList<String> alist=new ArrayList<String>();

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Bryan");
    person.setAge(18);
    person.setFavFood("Chicken Rice");

    // If you want multiple person to add, you need to use loops, and that way you can keep creating person objects and add them to list.
    // Suggesting, use separate method for that logic.

    alist.add(person);

    for (int i = 0; i <= alist.size(); i++) {
        Person p = alist.get(i);     
        System.out.println ("My Name: "+ p.getName());
        System.out.println ("Age: "+ p.getAge());
        System.out.println ("Favourite food: "+ p.getFavFood());      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your printing codes in a `For` loop. And loop is running 3 three times

```
alist.size()
```

means 3, you have 3 item in that list.

**This can be your object class:**

```
public class Table {

    int age;
    String name;
    String food;

    public Table(int age, String name, String food) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.food = food;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**And fill arraylist with your object:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Table> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    // this is how you fill
    alist.add(new Table(18, "Bryan", "Rice");

    for (int i = 0; i <= alist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("AGE: " + alist.get(i).age);
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: So what should I be using?

Comment: You need to create an object  for list. And fill it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String []args) {

    ArrayList<String> alist_name=new ArrayList<String>();  
    ArrayList<String> alist_value=new ArrayList<String>();  

    alist_name.add("My Name: ");
    alist_name.add("Age: ");
    alist_name.add("Favourite food: ");

    alist_value.add("Bryan");
    alist_value.add("18");
    alist_value.add("Chicken Rice");    

    for (int i = 0; i < alist_name.size(); i++) {     
      System.out.println (alist_name.get(i)+alist_value.get(i));    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You code is poorly formatted, you might want to improve it. Besides, although it works in this case, it does not generalize well to real situation.

Comment: I think the answer is ok for this user. he need a easy solution for his problem.

Comment: @ hkchengrex  You are right. i am agree with you. But in this case i just want to let the users know how arraylist is perform. so why i add this answer.